# Windows: Register URI-Scheme for specifically formatted http-URL

Tags: windows, uri, handler

I've found a lot on this page on how to register a certain URI-scheme to open using a particular application in windows.

All Q & A which I've found cover creating an own protocol for this purpose which which is unique for the application which should be registered.

My question is: Is there a way to open usual http/https-Links which contain a certain pattern/format using application A, instead of opening all http/https-links with the browser?

Example: I want, that all links which match the format `http://*.domainX.com/*` or `http://*.domainX.com/*`, should be opened using my own application instead of the browser.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can try [Registering the Application Handling the Custom URI Scheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx#app_ex)

> To register an application to handle a particular URI scheme, add a
>   new key, along with the appropriate subkeys and values, to
>   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. The root key must match the URI scheme that is
>   being added.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Could you please give an example on how to register a "sub"-class of the http-protocol, i.e. in the above question only a certain domain?

Comment: After searching, I wasn't able to find how to register for a subclass